# Very slow connect when using OCI connection pool

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

When using OCI (12.2.0.1.0) connection pools ([`OCIConnectionPoolCreate`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNOCI/oci16rel001.htm#GUID-7E5A69F2-0268-4655-845D-A7662902FAA2)) any call that establishes a connection (`OCILogon2`, `OCISessionGet`, `OCIServerAttach`) takes a very long time to complete (almost 10 seconds).

The pool names created by `OCIConnectionPoolCreate` all start with `OCI:CP...`  and strangely all these functions then call `getaddrinfo` four times trying to resolve the non-existent host `OCI` (which seems total nonsense). After this fails, a connection is properly established via the pool. All calls have the relevant mode specified (`OCI_LOGON2_CPOOL`, `OCI_SESSGET_CPOOL`).

Any idea what's wrong here? Using the session pools (whose names start with `OCI:SP...` works fine).

Comment: Does the same happen with OCI Session Pooling, which is the newer, generally preferred pooling solution?

Comment: Session Pooling works fine (despite using a similar string `OCI:SP...`) and that's what I'm using currently.